# converting computed column to a specific datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am currently trying to execute some SQL Query in SQLSERVER 2008 R2 form my Java GUI. I am working on currency management system.
I have to store Long data type values as the figure of currency may exceed than 10 digits but the computed column dose not show any data type option in the design view of the table. I really Need help regarding this as my value exceeds than 10 digits and I need to select total value from my database. I have tried to execute the code but its showing some sort of overflow error please help

The following is my script file of the table from database name CNV

```
USE [CNV]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[soil_det](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [rm_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [box_no] [int] NULL,
    [weight] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [note_state] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [dm_state] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [1] [int] NULL,
    [2] [int] NULL,
    [5] [int] NULL,
    [10] [int] NULL,
    [20] [int] NULL,
    [50] [int] NULL,
    [100] [int] NULL,
    [500] [int] NULL,
    [1000] [int] NULL,
    [tp]  AS (((((((([1]+[2])+[5])+[10])+[20])+[50])+[100])+[500])+[1000]),
    [tv]  AS (((((((([1]*(1)+[2]*(2))+[5]*(5))+[10]*(10))+[20]*(20))+[50]*(50))+[100]*(100))+[500]*(500))+[1000]*(1000)) PERSISTED,
    [tp_ex1]  AS ((((((([2]+[5])+[10])+[20])+[50])+[100])+[500])+[1000]),
    [tv_ex1]  AS ((((((([2]*(2)+[5]*(5))+[10]*(10))+[20]*(20))+[50]*(50))+[100]*(100))+[500]*(500))+[1000]*(1000)),
    [val_1]  AS ([1]*(1)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mut_det] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: It runs fine to me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b2ed/1

Comment: "Some sort of overflow error"? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes I will try to... When the total value exceeds than 10 digits it shows the following error.........."Error Source: .Net SQL type Data provider" AND "Error Message:Arithmetic overflow error converting datatype to int"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is solution for this , you can do something as given in image

Check the full article over here : [SQL SERVER – Puzzle – Solution – Computed Columns Datatype Explanation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/29/sql-server-puzzle-solution-computed-columns-datatype-explanation/)

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much for your valuable cooperation Pranay. But can we convert it into bigint datatype is yes the what should I replace